# How do I get Chronometer to work as a countdown timer in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, chronometer

I am making an app in android studio, and I want to be able to display the amount of time left until a certain time in the day. For some reason I can't seem to get my code to work; when I run my code  does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.end_chronometer);
mChronometer.setCountDown(true);
mChronometer.setBase(convertToDate(timeStr));

...

private long convertToDate(String str)
{
    try
    {
        DateFormat mDateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM");

        Date date = mDateTimeFormat.parse(str);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
}
```

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "I can't seem to get my code to work" means. Note that you are setting this to count down from 0 (`setBase()` with a value of `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`).

Comment: My Chronometer always displayed a value of zero, so how would I set the time I am counting down until?

Comment: Call `setBase()` with a time in the future, IIRC. So, add some number of milliseconds to `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`, and use that value for `setBase()`.

Comment: Ok, but what if my countdown timer isn't based on the number of seconds left until an event, but more specifically I know my timer wants to countdown to 1:15 pm, and I'm not sure when I'm going to start my timer. Do I just find the difference in time between the two times then add that to elapsedRealTime() ?

Comment: Okay, I think I got it working, Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CountDownTimer`.

```
 new CountDownTimer((hourOfDay * 60 + minute1) * 60 * 1000, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                SimpleDateFormat mTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
                mTvRemainTime.setText(mTimeFormat.format(new Date(millisUntilFinished)));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTvRemainTime.setText("stop");
            }
        }.start();
```